# How can i call the Add() function?

Tags: java, function, addition, calculator

i have been trying to make an easy calculator

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Math {
    
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    private static void Add(int a, int b,int c){
        
        System.out.println("First nummber...");
        a = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("secound nummber...");
        b = input.nextInt();
        
        c = a + b;
        
        System.err.println(c);
                
            
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Add();

    }

}
```

but i got this error

> The method Add(int, int, int) in the type Math is not applicable for the arguments ()

I tried then to add the variables to the Add() in the main function

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Add(a,b,c);

}
```

and then I got this error

```
Multiple markers at this line
                      - b cannot be resolved to a variable
                      - c cannot be resolved to a variable
                      - a cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Comment: I suggest you read about variable and parameter declarations. In particular, declaring `c` as a parameter is inappropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

because you haven't declared a,b and c.

try like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  Add(0,0,0);

 }
```

On side note, you are reading a and b again in your function. You can read them in your main and pass them to function.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner scanner =  new Scanner(System.in);

  int a = scanner.nextInt();

  int b = scanner.nextInt();      

  int c =  Add(a,b);

  System.out.println("Addtion of " + a + " and " + b + " is " + c);

 }
```

and then your Add function will get a and b and just add it.

```
  public static int Add(int a, int b){
     return a + b;
  }
```

Comment: Your new version of `Add()` is missing the return type.

Answer (score 1):

All of the other answers have pointed at the problem without providing what I would consider the correct solution. Since you are asking for the input from the user, it is inappropriate to declare the variables as parameters. Instead, you should declare local variables:

```
public class Math {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    private static void Add(){
        System.out.println("First nummber...");
        int a = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("secound nummber...");
        int b = input.nextInt();

        int c = a + b;

        System.err.println(c);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Add();
    }
}
```

Comment: remove the parameters from your method

Comment: @practice2perfect done. I missed that most important detail in my copy/paste. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared `Add()` as a method that accepts 3 arguments: `Add(int a, int b, int c)` and you're calling it with none.

Change the method signature from:

```
private static void Add(int a, int b,int c)
```

to:

```
private static void Add()
```

In addition to that, you'll have to declare a,b,c inside the method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Add();
}

private static void Add(){
    System.out.println("First number...");
    int a = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("second number...");
    int b = input.nextInt();
    int c = a + b;
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

***Side note*** 
do not use `System.err.` to print debug printings, use `System.out.println()`

Comment: thanks for the fast answer :)

but i tried to add the ints to the method 

Add( int a, int b, int c)

and i got this error " Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "int", delete 
  this token
 - Syntax error on token "int", delete 
  this token
 - Syntax error on token "int", delete 
  this token
 - a cannot be resolved to a variable
 - b cannot be resolved to a variable
 - c cannot be resolved to a variable "

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Math {

static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

private static void Add(){ //do not use arguments here for just calling it 

    System.out.println("First nummber...");
    int  a = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("secound nummber...");
    int b = input.nextInt();

    int c = a + b;

    System.err.println(c); //use System.out.println(c);



}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Add();

}

}
```

From your code, modifying this would work

Answer (score 0):

You can re-write your code like this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Math {

   static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

   private static int Add(int a, int b){    
       return a + b;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("First nummber...");
       int a = input.nextInt();
       System.out.println("secound nummber...");
       int b = input.nextInt();
       int c = Add(a,b);
       System.out.println(c);        

   }
```

}

But from your code I can see that you are really new to java perhaps new to programming. So I will recommend you to learn basic java and programming first. 
You can learn online from

- http://www.learnjavaonline.org/
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/

Or can read some books

- [Head First
  Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009208)
- [Thinking In
  Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131872486)

Answer (score -1):

ADD(1,2,3) would work ADD() will not

you have declared it with 3 arguments and you are providing it with none

Comment: Since the parameter values would be ignored, it is better to remove the parameters all together.